# Webservice asmx não retorna JSON, somente XML

Tags: c#, json, web-service, xml

Queria resolver esse problema, o retorno de minha webservice, retorna com o corpo em JSON, mas o cabeçalho em XML. como faço para retornar a estrutura em JSON ?

já li toda a internet e não consigo entender, vi uns scripts jQuery com ASP.NET mas minha aplicação tá em C#, alguém tem alguma ideia ?

segue retorno de minha consulta:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"id_produto":"27","nr_referencia":"1","nm_produto":"SKOL 600ML","path_foto":"","qtd_estoque":"
```